# JSF 2 : disable button when submitted using Richfaces 4

Tags: button, jsf-2, richfaces, submit

I am using JSF 2 and Richfaces 4, I need to disable button when submitted. I need to call the action of the button too. When the form validation fails, submit button should be enabled. I can do using Richfaces 3 but not been able to do with Richfaces 4.

Looking for the help.

Comment: You could easily do this with PrimeFaces and it shouldn't break RichFaces. `<p:commandButton value="Submit" widgetVar="myButton" action="#{myBean.submit()}" onstart="myButton.disable();" oncomplete="myButton.enable();" update=":someOuterComponentId"/>`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but for only this I do not want to use extra library. I would consider in future projects.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `onbegin` and `oncomplete` attributes of the `<a4j:commandButton>` for this.

```
<a4j:commandButton ... onbegin="disabled=true" oncomplete="disabled=false" />
```

Comment: Using a4j:commandButton I get following exception else with h:commandButton is works fine.
javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: java.lang.NullPointerException